# Timeout webservice call from client side in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm calling a jira rest webservice using java script. One requirement is to abort/timeout the call if it runs for more that 5 seconds. How would I achieve this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement **SignalR** in your application. This might help you and very easy to implement.
You can increase timeout also from web.config file but SignalR is more helpful.

Comment: I am calling it from servicenow freamework so option of using SignalIR is not available .